# Adjust default spacing of elements in math mode

Tags: spacing, amsmath

I want to automatically add a `\,` between the upperlimit and the integral sign instead of having to type it mannually every time. I'm using latexocr to snip the equation and copy the latex code from latexocr to my document, if i use `\renewcommand` to redefine `\int`, then the syntax would become `\int{a}{b}{f}` but i want to keep the `\int_{a}^{b}{f}` format where `_` and `^` is used to indicate upper and lower limit. Are there anyway to achieve this or are there any method to configure the default spacing of the original `\int` command ?

```
\let\st\int
\renewcommand*{\int}[3]{\st_{#1}^{\,#2}{#3}}

% but i want something like this
$\int_{a}^{b}{s}(x)dx$
% instead of this
$\int{a}{b}{s}(x)dx$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: And why do you want that? The default spacing looks better IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you really want to do this, it is a job for `\RenewDocumentCommand` and its `e`mbellishment argument type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\int}{t{\limits}e{_^}}{%
  \DOTSI\intop\ilimits@
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\limits}
  \IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}%
  \IfValueT{#3}{^{\IfBooleanF{#1}{\,}#3}}%
}
% just for comparison
\newcommand{\standardint}{\DOTSI\intop\ilimits@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(t)\,dt
\int_{a}^{b}f(t)\,dt
\\
\standardint_{a}^{b}f(t)\,dt
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

You do use `amsmath`, don't you?

[image]

By the way, the syntax for `\int` doesn't require braces around the integrand as you seem to believe: they're actually generally unwanted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to employ the Plain-TeX `\def` directive instead of the LaTeX `\renewcommand` directive. That said, I would define the new version of `\int` to take two arguments rather than three, as the version of the `\int` macro mentioned in the OP's query does nothing special with the third argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\st\int
\def\int_#1^#2{\st_{#1}^{\,#2}}

\begin{document}
$\int_a^b s(x)dx$ \quad $\int_{u}^{v} w(x)\,dx$
\end{document}
```